# Are repulsive and attractive gravity connected?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

My question is simple:

Can attractive and repulsive gravity (the expansion of space between masses, caused by the still hypothetical dark energy, so it **seems** they are repelled while in fact, they stay at the same place, like the well-known raisins in the rising bread) be separated or are they interdependent? In other words, can repulsive gravity exist without the attractive type and vice-versa? Of course (according to mainstream physics), on a cosmic scale, both kinds don't interfere with each other and can exist happily and independent of each other. But how was this situation, say, before inflation?

Comment: What is "repulsive gravity"?

Comment: What do you think "repulsive gravity" is?

Comment: You probably refer to dark energy verses matter as a repulsive and attractive gravity. If that so, they both exist in the same Einstein equation, and this is why they "live" together...

Comment: Repulsive gravity is the expansion of space between masses so it **seems** they are repelled while in fact, they stay at the same place (like the well-known raisins in the rising bread).

Comment: @descheleschilder: Please edit the question to make it clear that that's what you mean. Nobody is going to guess that from the current text of the question.

Comment: @BenCrowell- Done!

Comment: Given that dark energy is "still hypothetical" as you put it, wouldn't it be obvious then that attractive gravity can exist without repulsive gravity? After all, repulsive gravity isn't even proven to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it seems that OP is mainly interested in cosmological solutions, there is an interesting case without cosmological constant/dark energy where both repulsive and attractive gravity is present around an isolated massive charged body: overcharged [Reissner–Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric), when electric charge $|Q|>M$ (in GR units). There we have a region of repulsive gravity when $r<Q^2/M$, test mass would be pushed away from the center, while outside (at $r>Q^2/M$) there is a region with normal, attractive gravity. Thus a point mass could “hover” at an equilibrium radius $r=Q^2/M$. So, this example demonstrates that yes, repulsive gravity (when present) is interconnected with attractive.

A possible realization of this metric with a thin charged spherical shell with somewhat reasonable equation of state is considered [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1193).

Comment: But isn't the repulsive gravity, in this case, an illusion, of which the electrical forces are responsible?

Comment: The point mass here is an uncharged particle, feeling only the metric, not the electrical field.